# JFileChooser context menu language

Tags: java, internationalization, contextmenu, jfilechooser

I have a problem with changing language of context menu in JFileChooser. Until now i changed the language of most elements in JFileChooser by

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", rb.getString("button.cancel"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.saveButtonText", rb.getString("button.save"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.saveInLabelText", rb.getString("fileChooser.saveIn"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameLabelText", rb.getString("fileChooser.fileName"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText", rb.getString("fileChooser.filesOfType"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.acceptAllFileFilterText", rb.getString("fileChooser.acceptAllFile"));    
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.upFolderToolTipText", rb.getString("fileChooser.upFolderToolTipText"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.homeFolderToolTipText", rb.getString("fileChooser.homeFolderToolTipText"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderToolTipText", rb.getString("fileChooser.newFolderToolTipText"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewButtonToolTipText", rb.getString("fileChooser.detailsViewButtonToolTipText"));
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonToolTipText", rb.getString("fileChooser.listViewButtonToolTipText"));
```

but i cant find how to change language of right click context menu.

Comment: AFAIK they are system-values and not under controll of java.

Comment: You can set the locale of the `JFileChooser` as given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305087/how-to-set-language-in-java).

Comment: I have checked for example Japanese locale and it works but polish didnt. I dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to change the defaultLocale before calling anything from swing? Just try to change it in the main.

```
public static void main (String args []){
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```